# Decoding account data buffer from an account owner by Raydium Liquidity Pool V4

Tags: web3.js, deserialization

I'm trying to decode the account data buffer that is provided when calling methods such as getAccountInfo or getProgramAccounts with web3.js. The account in question is the account whose address is a Raydium ammid. Here is an example of such a buffer:[image]

The accounts is owned by Raydium Liquidity Pool V4 which doesn't have an IDL that I can use. I also have not been able to find a valid schema for the account data to deserialize with Borsh. Calling the "parsed" version of the web3 methods above doesn't deserialize the data either. I was wondering if anyone knows how to decode the data buffer in order to extract things such as token addresses associated with the ammid etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the program isn’t open source and you don’t have the IDL you can start by looking for SDK provided by the project or ask the team for more details and documentation.

Comment: In my experience they don’t really care about small programmers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `AccountLayout.decode(account.data)` or, if it's a mint address, `MintLayout.decode(account.data)`. Given that `account` is the response from `getAccountInfo`

These two are found in `@solana/spl-token`.

Comment: This is not correct, as `AccountLayout` from `spl-token` is meant for token accounts specifically, whereas this is a Raydium account of some sort (i.e. likely not a token account).

Comment: Understood. What is the solution, then? I'm a new dev, so I'm learning as well. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Like Wei said, if they don't publish their IDL there isn't really anything you can do outside of asking the team directly if you really care about the account layout. Usually you just care about calling the program, in which case youd use an sdk if they offer it.

Comment: (all this with the assumption that the contract is closed source obviously)